# How to calculate the sum of the output of the for loop for all iterations in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, machine-learning, comparison, evaluation

I have two different row vectors P and L. The algorithm has different P and L for each iteration, my code is supposed to count how many corresponding ones both row vectors have at the same place for example if P and L are:

```
P=[1,2,2,1,1]
L=[2,2,1,1,1]
```

The answer should be 2. If I have another P and L with the answer 3 for example, I should be able to sum 2 and 3 to give me 5.

My code computes the correct answer for each iteration,but I don't know how to sum these answers to get the total number of corresponding ones the vectors P and L have in all the iterations.

Here is my code:

```
     i = 1:numel(P); 
     j = 1:numel(L);
     Valuecompared=(P(i) == 1) & (L(j)==1);

     a=0;

   for k = 1:numel(Valuecompared)

   if Valuecompared(k) == 1
    a=a+1;
   end

   end
```

I have tried `sum(a), cumsum(a)` inside and outside the loop with index `k` and without, but it just gives me the same answer "a" without adding the previous computed answers of "a". Could it be because it gets overwritten and doesn't get saved each time?

Also, I cannot seem to store the value of "a" while the algorithm is running I can display it, but if I have 100 iterations that will not be convenient, how can I compute the sum answer for all iterations and store the total sum in one variable like `Atotal`?

Comment: You suspected right, it gets overwritten every time. See https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/76783-how-do-i-stoop-overwriting-the-variable-in-a-for-loop Anyway, this seems like a problem where you don't need a loop in the first place. Are P and L always the same length?

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger yes P and L are always the same length.

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger I actually came across something similar, but  I still cannot get the sum. The variable value compared keeps changing, which is fine but I want to be able to sum all the answers because I can't do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the `a` from each loop. Unfortunately you don't show the complete loop so I don't know over which variable you are iterating. But let's assume it is `q`. Then you have to define `a`outside the loop, e.g. with

```
a = zeros(1,niter); % niter = number of times you run the loop
```

Then you would have to replace the last lines with with something like

```
if Valuecompared(k) == 1
    a(q)=a(q)+1;
end
```

Once the loop is finished you can take the `sum(a)`

Alternatively you could move `a=0;`outside the loop, then you don't even have to take the sum anymore.

A bit offtopic, but you can replace all the code you have shown so far with

```
a = sum(P==1 & L==1)
```

Does exactly the same thing.

Comment: But I can't save P1,P2 or L.. into one matrix or vector because the algorithm produces them for each iteration; I do not have them saved. However, I tried this and still I only get the answer with no sum.

Comment: Ah, i tought you already had them beforehand. My bad, editing

Comment: It would help if you would post a more of your code so I can make a better example

Comment: Actually the algorithm just computes the P and L for a number of times before it completes one iteration. So there isn't a specific variable in my code. All the code that I'm working with is the one I showed. So right now I'm not sure what to put instead of the variable q.

Comment: Wait, just to get this straight: Is the whole code you showed in a loop?

Comment: Yes the algorithm executes the code each time it performs an iteration. It computes new P and L each time as well.

Comment: Can you post the beginning of the loop?

Comment: The machine learning architecture that I'm using has many functions and it executes these functions according to the number of epochs I specify. So there isn't really a specific place for a loop that I can point out unfortunately :(

Comment: Erm, from a coding perspective there definitely is a beginning at some point. If the code cycles multiple times over the shown part, it has to be inside a `for/while ..... end` construction.

Comment: I get your point now. I may have to search deeper in the code. There isn't a simpler way though? I thought that summing all the results is an easier task.

Comment: It really should be just a matter of scrolling up the code up to the point where the indent goes one back. You can automatically indent all your code with ctrl-a followed by ctrl-i .